# How to tune parameters of nested Pipelines by GridSearchCV in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

Is it possible to tune parameters of nested Pipelines in scikit-learn? E.g.:

```
svm = Pipeline([
    ('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2)),
    ('cls', LinearSVC(class_weight='auto'))
])

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfIdfVectorizer()),
    ('ova_svm', OneVsRestClassifier(svm))
})

parameters = ?

GridSearchCV(classifier, parameters)
```

If it's not possible to do this directly, what could be a workaround?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

scikit-learn has a double underscore notation for this, [as exemplified here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html). It works recursively and extends to `OneVsRestClassifier`, with the caveat that the underlying estimator must be explicitly addressed as `__estimator`:

```
parameters = {'ova_svm__estimator__cls__C': [1, 10, 100],
              'ova_svm__estimator__chi2_k': [200, 500, 1000]}
```

Answer (score 23):

For the estimator that you have created you can get the list of parameters with their tags as follows.

```
import pprint as pp

pp.pprint(sorted(classifier.get_params().keys()))
```

> ['ova_svm',  'ova_svm__estimator',  'ova_svm__estimator__chi2', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__chi2__k', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__chi2__score_func',  'ova_svm__estimator__cls', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__C', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__class_weight', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__dual', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__fit_intercept', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__intercept_scaling', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__loss',  'ova_svm__estimator__cls__max_iter',
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__multi_class', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__penalty', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__random_state', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__cls__tol',  'ova_svm__estimator__cls__verbose', 
>   'ova_svm__estimator__steps',  'ova_svm__n_jobs',  'steps', 
>   'vectorizer',  'vectorizer__analyzer',  'vectorizer__binary', 
>   'vectorizer__decode_error',  'vectorizer__dtype', 
>   'vectorizer__encoding',  'vectorizer__input', 
>   'vectorizer__lowercase',  'vectorizer__max_df', 
>   'vectorizer__max_features',  'vectorizer__min_df', 
>   'vectorizer__ngram_range',  'vectorizer__norm', 
>   'vectorizer__preprocessor',  'vectorizer__smooth_idf', 
>   'vectorizer__stop_words',  'vectorizer__strip_accents', 
>   'vectorizer__sublinear_tf',  'vectorizer__token_pattern', 
>   'vectorizer__tokenizer',  'vectorizer__use_idf', 
>   'vectorizer__vocabulary']

From this list you can then set the parameters you want to do a GridSearchCV on.

Comment: This is gold! Thank you!